# How to install Bash and Zsh on Asustor's NAS Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, nas, asustor

With an Asustor NAS (such as AS7004t-i5), we can `ssh` into the Linux that is running in the box.  But it is using `sh`.  There is no `bash`, `zsh`, and `apt-get` or `yum` doesn't work.  How do we install Bash and Zsh there?

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in [Asustor knowledge base](https://support.asustor.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/208/0/what-command-can-i-use-under-ssh), the system embedded is "similar to Linux but is not Linux" and the command list available it's also limited.

One option for install Linux packages can be "[Entware](https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki)".

I've installed this app from "App Central" and when it's finished you can install packages.

Example:

`# opkg find nano` to find "nano" package
`# opkg install nano` to install "nano"

Comment: It's not redhat, it's not ubuntu, but it's 100% a linux distribution, running a Linux kernel. The hint to use Entware is correct. Thanks.

Comment: If you read the post linked in my answer you can understand perfectly what means "similar to Linux but is not Linux". Is a short way to explain to not experts...

Comment: Maybe it's not an exact explanation because "it's a minimal Linux distribution" can be better (it's better because it's exact), but someone no expert can understand perfectly and can make a choice with foundation if it's necessary or not install "Entware" or any other software.

Comment: Angel Bonet, "similar to linux" is wrong and someone will downvote you. It's 100% Linux, no matter how big or small it is. In the 90's there were a lot of linux distribtutions fitting into 1.4MB floppies: they were Linux. Furthermore, some people says, Linux it's the kernel only. In such case, RedHat Linux, is a Linux kernel based distribution.

Comment: maxadamo... you are totally free to downvote all you want. Maybe you don't want to understand my explanation about the initial doubt. I think it's totally clear, in my opinion, and if somebody read the link (you mention my answer and the link used to explain in the easiest way possible a question presented by nonopolartiy), and my answer can understand the question.

Comment: I'm not here to find positive or negative votes... I'm here to help people in the same way the people help me... Think about this discussion, and think if help somebody. For me it's totally finished and I only want to send you the best possible whisses.

Comment: you're not helping anyone if you provide wrong information, and what you have written is technically wrong: Asustore OS is a full fledged Linux, but it has its own package management (operated through the Web UI), and Linux is not apt-get, or yum, or pacman. It's explained everywhere, what Linux is but I'm not gonna downvote you (despite you really deserve it because you're insisting in providing wrong information)

Comment: not experts will understand you very well if you simply write the truth: "it's linux, but it lacks a package manger such as apt or yum or pacman". Zebra is similar to horse (they belong to the same family), but Pony is a horse. Asustore and Floppy based Linux distributions are like Pony: horses. While FreeBSD is a zebra.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default shell by changing your users .profile

ssh onto the box

`opkg install zsh`

`vim .profile`

```
if [[ -x /opt/bin/zsh ]]; then
  export SHELL=/opt/bin/zsh
  exec /opt/bin/zsh
fi
```

If you want to install oh-my-zsh take a look at https://github.com/usercase/oh-my-zsh/

Answer (score 0):

Asustor uses a modified version of a full *nix distro busybox kind of like what they run on their range of routers AsusWRT *Kind of* its very similar..

As with AsusWRT (Busybox) Entware [optware replacement] is the way to install packages. nano etc..

If you take a look under the Asustor NAS > App Central > ..section you will see "Entware" Its with this package installed on the device you are then able to then install *.opkg packages from the registry/repo.

Alternatively, there is a side-loader available to Asustor NAS device to load .apk files not currently found in App Central.

Side-loaded .apk files via URL. This is off topic, none the less it still exists ;)

NB. For a helpful run down about this fairly undocumented package works you will find excellent info over on: [Merlin's AsusWRT Firmware github repo](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin.ng/wiki/Entware) which goes into detail on how this thing works and what useful tools can be used and it should prove a great guide for translating over into how Entware should function on Asustor NAS devices.

ASUSTOR NAS Specific [Notes](https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki/Install-on-ASUSTOR-NAS)

Entware [Wiki](https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki)